# is there a way to eager load polymorphic association's associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, eager-loading

artists have many activities (basically a cache of interactions between users):

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'Artist', :foreign_key => :receiver_id #owns the stuff done "TO" him
  belongs_to :link, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'Artist', :foreign_key => :creator_id #person who initiated the activity

end
```

For example:

```
  Activity.create(:receiver_id => author_id, :creator_id => artist_id, :link_id => id, :link_type => 'ArtRating')
```

I want to create an activity stream page for each artist, consisting of a list of different types of events, ArtRatings (likes, dislikes), Favoriting, Following etc.

The controller looks like this:

```
class ActivityStreamController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = @artist.activities.includes([:link,:creator,:receiver]).order("id DESC").limit(30)
  end
end
```

The db call correctly eagerly loads the polymorphic link objects:

```
  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE (("activities"."receiver_id" = 6 OR "activities"."creator_id" = 6)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30
  ArtRating Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "art_ratings".* FROM "art_ratings" WHERE "art_ratings"."id" IN (137, 136, 133, 130, 126, 125, 114, 104, 103, 95, 85, 80, 73, 64)
  SELECT "follows".* FROM "follows" WHERE "follows"."id" IN (14, 10)
  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."id" IN (25, 16, 14)
```

But when I display each ArtRating, I also need to reference the post title, which belongs to a post.  In the view, if I do:

```
activity.link.post
```

It does a separate DB call for each art_rating's post.  Is there a way to eagerly load the post as well?

**UPDATE TO THE QUESTION:**

If there is no way to achieve eager loading of posts using 'includes' syntax, is there a way to manually do the eager loading query myself and inject it into the @activities object?

I see in the DB log:

```
SELECT "art_ratings".* FROM "art_ratings" WHERE "art_ratings"."id" IN (137, 136, 133, 130, 126, 125, 114, 104, 103, 95, 85, 80, 73, 64)
```

Is there a way I can access this list of ids from the @activities object?  If so, I could do 2 additional queries, 1 to get the art_ratings.post_id(s) in that list, and another to SELECT all posts IN those list of post_ids.  Then somehow inject the 'post' results back into @activities so that it's available as activity.link.post when I iterate through the collection.  Possible?

Comment: From what I understand, you have a set of models that are supposed to be attached to activities as links and I gather they all share at least one association, which is `post`. Is there maybe enough common ground in these link models to use [Single Table Inheritance](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base) and put all in one table?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR my solution makes `artist.created_activities.includes(:link)` eager load everything you want**

Here's my <del>first</del> attempt at it: https://github.com/JohnAmican/music

A few notes:

- <del>I'm relying on `default_scope`, so this isn't optimal.</del>
- It looks like you're using STI. My solution doesn't. That means you can't simply call `activities` on an artist; you have to reference `created_activities` or `received_activities`. There might be a way around this. I'll update if I find anything.
- I changed some names around because it was confusing to me otherwise.

<del>If you go into console and do `created_activities.includes(:link)`, the appropriate stuff gets eager-loaded:</del>

```
irb(main):018:0> artist.created_activities.includes(:link)
  Activity Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."creator_id" = ?  [["creator_id", 1]]
  Rating Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."id" IN (1)
  RatingExplanation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "rating_explanations".* FROM "rating_explanations" WHERE "rating_explanations"."rating_id" IN (1)
  Following Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "followings".* FROM "followings" WHERE "followings"."id" IN (1)
  Favorite Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "favorites".* FROM "favorites" WHERE "favorites"."id" IN (1)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Activity id: 1, receiver_id: 2, creator_id: 1, link_id: 1, link_type: "Rating", created_at: "2013-10-31 02:36:27", updated_at: "2013-10-31 02:36:27">, #<Activity id: 2, receiver_id: 2, creator_id: 1, link_id: 1, link_type: "Following", created_at: "2013-10-31 02:36:41", updated_at: "2013-10-31 02:36:41">, #<Activity id: 3, receiver_id: 2, creator_id: 1, link_id: 1, link_type: "Favorite", created_at: "2013-10-31 02:37:04", updated_at: "2013-10-31 02:37:04">]>
```

<del>At the very least, this proves that Rails has the ability to do this. Circumventing `default_scope` seems like an issue with telling Rails what you want to do rather than a technical limitation.</del>

**UPDATE:**

Turns out that when you pass a scope block to an association and call that association, `self` within that block refers to the relation. So, you can reflect on it and act appropriately:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator,  class_name: 'Artist', foreign_key: :creator_id,  inverse_of: :created_activities
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'Artist', foreign_key: :receiver_id, inverse_of: :received_activities
  belongs_to :link, -> { self.reflections[:activity].active_record == Rating ? includes(:rating_explanation) : scoped }, polymorphic: true
end
```

I updated my code to reflect (haha) this.

This can be cleaned up. For example, maybe you don't always want to eager load `rating_explanations` when accessing activity links. There are a number of ways to solve that. I could post one if you'd like.

But, I think the most important thing that this shows is that **within the association's scope block, you have access to the `ActiveRecord::Relation` being built. This will allow you to do things conditionally to it.**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@artist.activities.includes([{:link => :post},:creator,:receiver])...
```

[See the Rails docs for more.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Eager+loading+of+associations)

Comment: normally that would work, but docs don't say anything about eager loading through the polymorphic association.  Get error: "Association named 'post' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"

Comment: I tested this and it works fine (3.2.14). Are you sure all your "link"  associations have the post association?

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, you not only want to load a **polymorphic association's association**, but a **polymorphic association's *polymorphic* association**.

This basically means joining one defined table with another defined table through a bunch of undefined tables that come from some fields in the database.

Since both the activity and the post are joined through a polymorphic object they both have a `something_id` and `something_type` column.

Now I think active record doesn't let you do this out of the box but basically you want something like:

```
class Activity
  has_one :post, :primary_key => [:link_id, :link_type], :foreign_key => [:postable_id, :postable_type]
end
```

(assuming your polymorphic association on `Post` is `belongs_to :postable`)

That would then give you a query sort-of direct association between `Post` and `Activity` that is a very weird take on `habtm` with a 'polymorphic join table' (I just made that term up). Because both share the same polymorphicly associated object, they can be connected. Sort of like a friends-of-my-friends thing.

**CAVEAT**: Like I said, as far as I know, AR doesn't let you do this out of the box (though it would be awesome) but there are some gems that give you composite foreign and/or primary keys. Maybe you can find one to help you solve your problem in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This simple `ActiveRecord` should work:

```
@artist.activities.includes([:link => :post,:creator,:receiver]).order("id DESC").limit(30)
```

If not, if you are getting an error like `"Association named 'post' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"`, then you have a model problem, because at least one of your `link` associations doesn't have the `post` association.

Polymorphic associations are intended to be used with a common interface. If you ask for the `post` for any of the polymorphic association, then ALL of your associations should implemented also that association (the `post` one).

Check that all of your models used in the polymorphic association implement the post association.

Answer (score 0):

Given your update to the question (that this isn't feasible using AR's `include`), you could try the following to get the associated Posts with a single extra query:

- fetch the Activities, then build an Array of their linked `post_ids`.

  ```
  @activities = @artist.activities.includes([:link,:creator,:receiver])
  activity_post_ids = @activities.map{|a| a.link.post_id}.compact
  ```
- then load the posts in one query and store them in a `Hash`, indexed by their `id`

  ```
  activity_posts = Hash[Post.where(id: activity_post_ids).map{|p| [p.id, p]}]
  #=> {1 => #<Post id:1>, 3 => #<Post id:3>, ... }
  ```
- finally loop over `@activities` and set the `post` attribute of each associated link

  ```
  @activities.each{|a| a.link.post = activity_posts[a.link.post_id]}
  ```